# How to prevent last navigator stack from popping?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I use `Navigator.of(context).pop()` from different pages when user is unauthorized. But there are cases when it is called from homepage which causes app to crash since it pops the last navigator stack.
Is there a way to prevent my last navigator stack from popping?

I am using `onGenerateRoute` for navigation.

Comment: Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('Your home route name here')); This will pop all routes until it reaches home. This won't pop the home route.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to go to homepage after each unauthorized error. It is just a specific case

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if the route is the only route in the navigator while popping, you can try this:

```
// Make your custom predicate
bool firstModalRoute(Route<dynamic> route) => route.isFirst;

// Use it like this
Navigator.of(context).popUntil(firstModalRoute);
```

You can do it inline too:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
```

But, it is better in my opinion to make a utility method *firstModalRoute* for reusability.

---

## References:

- [PopUntil Method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html)
- [Route predicates](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RoutePredicate.html)
- [Route class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Route-class.html)

Comment: Thanks but this would rather just pop until the first page